# Column having maximum L2 norm

Tags: r

How to find the column of a matrix which has the maximum L2 norm? The matrix has NA values in some columns, we want to ignore those columns.

The following code I am trying, but it shows error due to NA values.

#The matrix is T

```
for(i in 1:ncol(T)){

if(norm(y,type='2') < norm(T[,i],type = '2'))

y = T[,i]
}
```

I think it would also be useful if we could somehow get the columns of T as a list, since we could use which.max function then, but I could not do that. Is that possible?

Please help

Comment: Quick note: naming anything `T` is a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can write your own L2 norm and find the column with the maximum, i.e.,

```
which.max(sqrt(colSums(T**2)))
```

**Example**

```
T <- matrix(c(1:10,NA,12:19,NA),nrow = 4)
> T
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    5    9   13   17
[2,]    2    6   10   14   18
[3,]    3    7   NA   15   19
[4,]    4    8   12   16   NA

> which.max(sqrt(colSums(T**2)))
[1] 4
```

Comment: Also, is there a way to get the columns of a matrix in a list?

Comment: @Martund yes, `as.list(data.frame(T))`